# Sticky toastr onclick event of close button

Tags: jquery, toastr

Is there a way I can perform an action after a user either clicks on the notification or clicks on the close button? At the moment I can do the first option using the options.onclick event. However I can not see how I can do this on the close button. Alternatively is there a way it could perform my action on the notification fading out?

```
toastr.options = {
    "closeButton": true,
    "timeOut": "0",
    "extendedTimeOut": "0"
};
toastr.options.onclick = function () {
    console.log("Notification clicked");
};
toastr.success("Success, Whooo!!");
```

Comment: I have not used toastr, but why could you not bind a click action to the close id or class jquery: $(".closeClass or #ID").click(function(){Do Something here});

Comment: See this: https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr#callbacks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't do it nicely on click, because there is no callback. You could use a jquery live handler on the button.

About the notification after fading out, use this;

```
 toastr.options.onHidden = function() { console.log("onHide"); };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
toastr.options.onCloseClick = function() { console.log("You clicked close button!"); };
```

If you use **onHidden** instead of **onCloseClick**, when it times out it will be triggered even if you didn't click it.

Answer (score 0):

toastr.options.onCloseClick= function() { console.log("You clicked close button!"); };

its working for me